# Adding Google Analytics User ID tracking to Joomla

Tags: google-analytics, joomla, userid

I use Joomla 3.7.2 for my website and would like to enable the Google Analytics User ID feature to discover how registered users interact with my site.  I need to add the following line to my tracking code to send User-ID data to Google Analytics:

```
ga('set', 'userId', {{USER_ID}}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

However I think I need to change the USER_ID part of the code to something else in order to 'pull' the unique identifier from my site. What code should I use for a Joomla website to do this?

I've seen this code in another post:

```
$return = $model->register($data);
if($return == 'useractivate'){$userid = JFactory::getUser($username)->id;}
```

...but I'm not sure how this relates to the previous code or where to implement this on my website.  Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking this page: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=871090? The `{{USER_ID}}` should be a system generated, unique identifier provided when the user logs in.

Comment: I have but I didn't understand what was suppose to replace the {{USER_ID}} part of the code!

Comment: Do you have any idea how I automatically grab the unique identifier?

Comment: I'm not sure but did you have a look in the link I posted? Also here https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser

Comment: Yes I had a look, but it doesn't explain how the code works - I'm still at a loss as to how to implement user-ID tracking in Google analytics.  I use sh404sef plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the user\_id from the Joomla-Framework on insert/update a (new) user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558859/how-to-return-the-user-id-from-the-joomla-framework-on-insert-update-a-new-use)

Comment: My query is slightly different - it's about how I can give Google Analytics a User ID.